isMutable always returning none value
async def get_metadata(self, address):
    metadata_account_info = await self.get_pda(address)

    if metadata_account_info.value:
        # Define the structure of the metadata account
        self.metadata_layout = CStruct(
            "key" / U8,
            "updateAuthority" / Bytes(32),
            "mint" / Bytes(32),
            "data" / CStruct(
                "name" / String,
                "symbol" / String,
                "uri" / String,
                
            ),
            "isMutable" / Bool
            
        )

From this simple script of retrieving the metadata that is relevant for me, why do i always retrieve a none-value of "isMutable"?

Rather than using String, which doesn't have a size, you might need to specify the exact sizes as bytes for name / symbol / uri. Take a look at the type sizes at https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata/blob/538f5b9776c279ed1ef2b4b66b225b96d5fb38b9/programs/token-metadata/program/src/state/metadata.rs#L22 and make sure that your isMutable lines up with it!

Before I made it to string, I used the bytes as I saw some references that used bytes,
"data" / CStruct(
"name" /  Bytes(32),
"symbol" / Bytes(10),
"uri" / Bytes(200),
I kept adjusting these bytes to do a tests if the value of isMutable will change but it did not. I hope you got more info about this issue. Thanks!

Try adding 4 bytes for the encoded length of each field (name, symbol, and uri), and you should be able to get it. So you should do CStruct( "name_length" / Bytes(4), "name" / Bytes(32), "symbol_length" / Bytes(4), "symbol" / Bytes(10), "uri_length" / Bytes(4), "uri" / Bytes(200)
